# Bifurcation and stability analyses of delay differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, packages, matlab

Are there any packages in Mathematica for bifurcation and stability analyses of delay differential equations? For Matlab, there is a nice tool like:

https://twr.cs.kuleuven.be/research/software/delay/ddebiftool.shtml

I'm looking for something similar to the above in Mathematica, for analyzing the following equations:

$$S'(t) = 0.31 S(t) \Big( 1 - \frac{S(t)}{6.19} \Big)- \frac{a}{1 + B(t)} S(t),$$

$$B'(t) = c (1 - B(t)) - d B(t) S(t) - 3 c (1 - B(t - 18)),$$

where $a = 0.71$, $c = 0.24$, and $d = 0.43$ (and the initial conditions could be: $S(0) = 0.98$ and $B(0) = 1.11$).

```
so = NDSolve[{ss'[t] + 0.71/(1 + bb[t]) ss[t] - 0.31 ss[t] (1 - ss[t]/6.19) == 0, 
bb'[t] - 0.24 (1 - bb[t]) + 0.43 bb[t] ss[t] + 0.72 (1 - bb[t - 18]) == 0, ss[t /; t < 0] == 0.98, bb[t /; t < 0] == 1.11}, {ss, bb}, {t, 0, 24}]
```

**EDIT**

Documentation of the Matlab package:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.7144.pdf

https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/513001.513002

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what's "bifurcation and stability analyses"? Not everybody knows it, I'm afraid. (The linked package isn't that well-documented, either. )

Comment: It would help if you have the example in copy-pastable format. Also useful would be to show the expected results for this (or perhaps a simpler) example.

Comment: One issue I ran into is that I cannot solve your system beyond `t=47` or so. I think this is due to a denominator getting very small. Actually I can get passed that using high precision, but it still limits me to around `t=108`.

Comment: Sorry, Mathematica lacks a continuation/bifurcation package for even ordinary differential equations, like [Content](http://www.sgtnd.narod.ru/science/nummeth/bifsoft/content/eng/download.htm) or [AUTO](http://indy.cs.concordia.ca/auto/).  But what do you want to explore with it?  Do you have a parameter to vary?

Comment: If `bb` represents a physical quantity, I'd be concerned that it goes negative around `t==41`.  The `-0.72 (1 - bb[t - 18])` term seems responsible.  What's the justification for using delay differential equations for your problem?

Comment: @Tim I haven't used DDEs myself, but in general, I think the state of the system should stay "in bounds" naturally.  Makes me wonder whether your DDE is good model for the system.  Maybe another formulation would be better?